# Cannot upload ICO file for Favicon ("File validation failed")

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, image-upload, favicons, magento2.4.3

Under *Content* » Design » *Configuration* (then *Edit* on the respective Theme) » Other Settings » *HTML Head* » **Favicon Icon** I am unable to upload any `.ico` files, even though the setting says the following:

> Maximum file size: 2 MB. Allowed file types: JPG, GIF, PNG, **ICO**, APNG.

Magento responds with

```json
{"error":"File validation failed.","errorcode":0}
```

Are there any special prerequisites for uploading `.ico` files in general? It works with PNG files for example, but not with ICO files.

- Magento `2.4.3`
- PHP `7.4.21`